# How to make the scrollbar in the window to work?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The scrollbar is there, the mousewheel is also binded but the scrollbar itself isn't acting the way it should. The scrollbar just stays on it's place and doesn't act in realtime. What should be done?

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk



def on_window1():

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("794x470")
    top.title('Optimized Map 1')


    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(top, width=400, height=280)
    canvas1.grid(row=0,column=200)

    for i in range(40):
        l3 = tk.Label(canvas1, text="Number of Rectangles:" + str(i))
        canvas1.create_window(50,21*i, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)

    myscrollbar= tk.Scrollbar(top,orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=canvas1.yview)
    myscrollbar.grid(row=0,column=200, sticky=tk.NS)
    #canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
    canvas1.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas1.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))



    #l4 = tk.Label(canvas1, text="Number of Rectangles:")
    #canvas1.create_window(50,21, window=l4, anchor=tk.NW)

window = tk.Tk()


b1 = tk.Button(window, text="Next", command=on_window1)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the `scrollregion` attribute of the canvas, which tells tkinter how much of the virtual canvas is being used. Most often, this is set to the *bounding box* as returned by the `bbox` command.

The `bbox` command returns the coordinates of a box that contains a set of elements. If you pass it the string `"all"` it will return the coordinates of a box that encompasses all objects in the canvas.

Once you've added everything to the canvas, add this line of code:

```
canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: The scrollbar goes back up to the top itself, do we have to add something else too?